# Why is there a DOUBLING step in HAKMEM 169

Tags: bit

In HAKMEM 169, there's a step which sums up the number of 1's in adjacent octets.

Precisely, I'm referring to the following link: http://www.verious.com/qa/fast-implementation-of-operations-on-large-sets-of-quite-big-integers/

```
// This is accomplished by right-shifting tmp by three bits, adding
// it to tmp itself and ANDing with a suitable mask. This yields a number in
// which groups of six adjacent bits (starting from the LSB) contain the number
// of 1Â¡Ã¤s among those six positions in n.
```

* (tmp + (tmp >> 3)) & 030707070707

What I'd like to know is if there was really any need for this DOUBLING from octet (3 bits) to double-octet(6 bits). If doubling was not done, would doing modulus 7 not give the desired result?

Say the value of temp without the DOUBLING operation is 00000002153 (octet). Modulus 7 (2^3-1) would give us 2+1+5+3, which is the number of bits which are set. Then is there really any need for DOUBLE operation?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason for this. The answer is that each octet could have a value from 0-7. If we add two octet and do modulus 7, we may loose some bits. For example,

2158H before doubling step implies that there are 2+1+5+8 which is fine. However, what happens if the value is 7676H before doubling step. In that case, the result will be 0+6+0+6. That is wrong.

As a result, doubling of octet to consider 6 bits is essential.

Answer (score 0):

In base `n` (base-64 in this case), taking the modulus `(n-1)` gives you the sum of the digits in that base; but it's that sum mod-`(n-1)`.  Mod-7 would always give you an answer less than 7, and a 32-bit word might have 7 or more bits set.

The more familiar trick that works on the same principle is testing for divisibility by nine.  If the sum of all of the decimal digits is a multiple of nine then the number is divisible by nine.  If the sum is not obviously divisible by nine (because it's large), you can use the same technique on the result to reduce it until the result is a single digit.

Unfortunately division is an expensive operation, so it's likely more efficient to use this common form:

```
x = (x & 0x55555555) + ((x >> 1) & 0x55555555);
x = (x & 0x33333333) + ((x >> 2) & 0x33333333);
x = (x & 0x0f0f0f0f) + ((x >> 4) & 0x0f0f0f0f);
x = (x & 0x00ff00ff) + ((x >> 8) & 0x00ff00ff);
x = (x & 0x0000ffff) + ((x >> 16) & 0x0000ffff);
```